# Does "definite" imply "symmetric"?

Tags: matrices, definition

In some definitions of "definite" for matrices, it is required that it should be "symmetric". Why is that?

When you use the definition

> $M \text{ positive definite} \Leftrightarrow \forall x : xMx^T > 0$

I don't see, why $M$ would have to be symmetric for that to make sense and to be written down.

Comment: If we do not demand symmetric, note that $M$ is positive definite iff the symmetric matrix $\frac 12(M+M^T)$ is. In fact, $xMx^T=x(\frac12(M+M^T))x^T$.

Comment: the short answer is because one usually likes to define bilinear forms for such matrices, which should be symmetric in their arguments.